# get value from formdata from MultipartDataStream not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
POST http://myserver.com/QCCSvcHost/MIME/RealtimeTrans/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="XbCY" Host: na-w-lxu3
Content-Length: 1470 Expect: 100-continue Connection: Keep-Alive

--XbCY Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=PayloadType

X12_270_Request_005010X279A1
--XbCY Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=ProcessingMode

RealTime
--XbCY Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=PayloadID

e51d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6fa6
```

My below code only gives name in the above case `name = "payloadID"`  but I don't get value which must be  "`e51d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6fa6`"

My code:

```
var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<MemoryStreamDataProvider>(new MemoryStreamDataProvider());

//access form data
NameValueCollection formData = provider.FormData;

//access files
IList<HttpContent> files = provider.Files;

//Example: reading a file's stream like below
HttpContent file1 = files[0];
Stream file1Stream = await file1.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

The formData has array of name payloadID, realtime etc but not the value.